# Hapi validation for req.user.id and payload id

Tags: node.js, validation, hapi.js, joi

I am having simple route in hapi

```
const handler = async(request, reply) => {
  const id = Helpers.extractUserId(request)
  const payload = request.payload
  if (payload.recipient !== id) {
    // my code....
  } else {
    return reply({ success: false, message: '_id and recipient id should not match' })
    //I want to return this from routeConfig itself
  }
}

const routeConfig = {
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/requestfriend',
  config: {
    auth:'jwt',
    validate: {
      payload: {
        recipient: Joi.string().required().error(new Error('recipient is required'))
      }
    },
    handler
  }
}
```

I put a condition for `if (payload.recipient !== id)` which mean logged in user's id and payload recipient's are same then it should throw the error...

Instead of doing this I want to put this condition in `routeConfig` itself... So is there any parameter which can be used here just like `auth`, `validate`, `handler`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends on what you want to do… If you are trying to authenticate user based on id, I advise you to check [the relevant part of the doc](https://hapijs.com/tutorials/auth)

Really easy to implement:

- Define a `validate` function in your server.js
- Add authentication option in your route config

If the validation function return `false` your endpoint will return a `401` error.

Comment: Do you try to validate your condition as a Joi validation ? That might also be possible. Maybe You want just to authenticate a user ?

Comment: can you please give an example

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your payload with [hapi route validation options](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/API.md#route.options.validate.payload)
This is the notation.

```
validate: {
    payload: async (value, options) => {
    }
}
```

Here is the explanation

> a validation function using the signature async function(value,
>   options) where:
>
> value - the request.payload object containing the request query parameters.
>
> options - options.
>
> if a value is returned, the value is
>   used as the new request.payload value and the original value is stored
>   in request.orig.payload.
>
> Otherwise, the payload is left unchanged. If
>   an error is thrown, the error is handled according to failAction.

Here is the sample code according to your application, this is just a dump sample, but I hope you can understand the idea here. You can validate payload, query and params object individually in every request. Just pass Joi validator or a function to validate incoming data.

```
const routeConfig = {
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/requestfriend',
    config: {
        auth: 'jwt',
        validate: {
            payload: async (value, options) => {
                // extract recipient data from payload
                const {recipient} = value;
                // you can now validate your recipient
                const result = Joi.validate({recipient}, Joi.string().required().error(new Error('recipient is required')), {abortEarly: false});
                if(result.error) throw Boom.badRequest(result.error);
                // there is no request object here, you have to dig in options.context parameter
                // this is how it's look like
                // {
                //     context:
                //         {
                //             headers:
                //                 {
                //                     host: 'localhost:3009',
                //                     'user-agent': 'curl/7.54.0',
                //                     accept: '*/*',
                //                     'content-length': '13',
                //                     'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                //                 },
                //             params: {},
                //             query: {x: 'y'},
                //             auth:
                //                 {
                //                     isAuthenticated: false,
                //                     isAuthorized: false,
                //                     credentials: null,
                //                     artifacts: null,
                //                     strategy: null,
                //                     mode: null,
                //                     error: null
                //                 },
                //             app: {route: {}, request: {}}
                //         },
                //     abortEarly: false
                // }

                // let's say we got id parameters here
                const id = Helpers.extractUserId(options.context);
                if(id !== recipient) throw Boom.badRequest('_id and recipient id should not match')
            }
        },
        handler
    }
}
```